# Autosys Client - JIL command execution Error

Tags: dns, autosys, jil

1. yst_c_testInbound is an existing job in the box yst_b_test_Inbound_U01.
2. Changing DNS alias name from old DNS name "str-uat.capint.com" to new DNS name "str-r7uat.capint.com"
3. set AUTOSERV & set SERVER1 & set SERVER2 being set properly.
4. Job is created successfully if the machine name is given for the tag "machine" in the jil file content. Old DNS name also working file.
5. It is giving the following Error for the new DNS name. Pls let me know what is the issue with DNS.
6. ping of the str-r7uat.capint.com is working fine

Error:
C:\AutoSys_Tools\bin>jil < yst_c_testInbound.jil

---

CAUAJM_I_50323 Inserting/Updating job: yst_c_testInbound
CAUAJM_E_10281 ERROR for Job: yst_c_testInbound < machine 'str-r7uat.capint.com' does not exist >
CAUAJM_E_10302 Database Change WAS NOT successful.

---

CAUAJM_E_50198 Exit Code = 1

---

## JIL file Content - yst_c_testInbound.jil

update_job: yst_c_testInbound      job_type: CMD
box_name: yst_b_test_Inbound_U01
command: perl -w $SYSTR_PL/strInBound.pl -PortNo 12222
machine: str-r7uat.capint.com
owner: testulnx
permission:
date_conditions: 0
description: "JMS Flow process to send the messages from STR to MQ"
std_out_file: ">>$STR_LOG/tradeflow_arts_impact_$$YST_STR_CURR_BUS_DATE.log"
std_err_file: ">>$STR_LOG/tradeflow_arts_impact_$$YST_STR_CURR_BUS_DATE.log"
alarm_if_fail: 0
profile: "/apps/profile/test_profile"
alarm_if_terminated: 0
timezone: US/Eastern

While creating the job using the JIL file yst_c_testInbound.jil

Getting below error

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the machine first. You cant update a job with not defined machine.
If you run:

```
autorep -M str-r7uat.capint.com
```

It will most likely return CAUAJM_E_50111 Invalid Machine Name: str-r7uat.capint.com

so add the machine first, then you can run the update job JIL.
Cheers.